# How to generate a bilinear group of prime order p for key generation

Tags: rsa, public-key, post-quantum-cryptography, key-generation

I am trying to implement an IEEE Paper In Cryptography. I read many reference regarding an RSA key generation. But i am confused with above statement. Please someone explain me What it says with example.

[image]

**EDIT <sup>*</sup>**

I am trying to implement key generation from the paper [Key-Aggregate Cryptosystem for Scalable Data Sharing in Cloud Storage](http://vertexsoft.co.in/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Key-Aggregate-Cryptosystem-for-Scalable-Data-Sharing-in-Cloud-Storage.pdf). In the paper, the first step in key generation is a setup phase state as follows
SETUP(1^λ) : Randomly pick a bilinear group G of prime order p where
[image], a generator gϵG ...

In the definition I understand what is meant by bilinear, prime order and generator. But what is that parameter λ and what should its value be?

---

<sub><sup>*</sup>Edit was added for clarification purposes (copy-and-paste from [this dupe](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/30948/what-is-the-security-parameter-in-kac-key-generation) by same user).</sub>

Comment: @fgrieu : Sorry, thats my mistake. Actually i am trying to do this paper as part of my academic project for completion of my graduation, Please can you give me some thread to do that or some explanations?

Comment: At least can you please give me suggestion about how to generate  public system parameters  that explaining in setup phase (section 4.1) @fgrieu

Comment: For what its worth: follow-ups to this paper include [this](http://esatjournals.net/ijret/2014v03/i11/IJRET20140311062.pdf), [this](http://www.ijarcsse.com/docs/papers/Volume_5/7_July2015/V5I7-0169.pdf), [this](http://www.slideshare.net/naseem23/1st-48043647), [this](http://www.slideshare.net/MugeshMukkandan/key-aggregate-cryptosystem-for-scalable-data-sharing-in-cloud-storage-44150667), [this](http://www.ijergs.org/files/documents/DATA-119.pdf). There is also a [variant](https://ir.nctu.edu.tw/bitstream/11536/23371/1/000329051500019.pdf) of the paper, used in the original question's bitmap.

Comment: One of the reference you mentioned uses AES for implementation. How it will be suitable under public/secret encryption? @fgrieu .you people got the solution? still i am in stuck :( :( :(

Comment: the last reference you mentioned is the exact paper i am trying to implement  @fgrieu

Comment: The main intend of my list is to make you ask yourself if you want to be another in the list of those "_**forced** to implement this paper as part of academic project_", as you put it. +1 for noticing that AES won't help reach the stated goal.

Comment: @John Mathew : Have you completed the project yet?
if so can you help me in bilinear mapping.
I too working on it and doesn't found an exact solution solution to this problem.
Please help me by providing the simple mathematical example on bilinear mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bilinear group in question is expected to be strong enough, and this depends on group order $p$. Namely, group order should be large enough. So, $\lambda$ is order size in bits. That is, size of the binary representation of order. Order of the group, or maybe just size of the order should be known before generating the group. Notation $1^{\lambda}$ is there to say SETUP() accepts a bitstring of size $\lambda$.

Comment: So may λ can be 512,1024, or more strong. Am i correct?? @Vadym Fedyukovych

Comment: For a multiplicative group, group order could be 200 bits long and modulus could be 1500 bits. For this particular bilinear group please double-check your source.  @John Mathew

Comment: I think the key generation process is something like ElGamal Encryption. Am i right?@fgrieu

Comment: Encrypt(pk,i,m)Phase in section 4.1 define that compute Cipher text C=<g^t,(vgi)^t,m. e(g1,gn)^t> . but what is that mapping  e ? Can you explain with a real example? sorry for bad math notations. @fgrieu

Comment: I am forced to implement this paper as part of academic project. So no way to escape from this. I should find a solution to do this. So  can i confirm that key generation is like El Gamal. If yes, then my next problem is e^. Again i am in trouble :(  @fgrieu?

Comment: @John Mathew: that might be the right moment for a (carefully thought) rebellion; or at least, asking whoever makes you "_forced to implement this paper as part of academic project_" to justify why he or she chooses that paper, or/and where to look to meaningfully fill the gaps that this paper contains. Perhaps, watch [Dead Poets Society](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_Poets_Society).

Comment: For a bilinear map, $\mathbb G_T$ is a multiplicative group. Both groups should be chosen by Setup() such that a non-trivial map exists. It is somewhat unclear whether group order is given to Setup() or it should be generated there. $\alpha\in_R\mathbb Z_p$ means $\alpha$ is a random element of $\mathbb Z_p$.  @fgrieu

Comment: Map $e(,)$ is the core of the whole scheme. Maybe an introductory review paper would help. This will take time. Please consider to take a look at https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/thesis.pdf. Sign $^$ is power-to, since $e(g,g)$ is a generator of  $\mathbb G_T$.  @John Mathew

Comment: @fgrieu: There was an update on map $\hat e$ at  http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/31010/how-to-calculate-mapping-in-bilinear

Comment: @Vadym Fedyukovych: I see. Your suggestion to use PBC seems good in the situation. I have read the paper more, and section 5.2 does contain a reference to PBC, and tells the parameters used in the implementation.